# Why is pandas.series.str.extract not working here but working elsewhere

Tags: python, pandas, extract

Why is a pandas.series.extract(regex) able to print the correct values, but won't assign the value to an existing variable using indexing or np.where.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['1', np.nan, np.nan, '1 Banana St, 69126 Heidelberg'],
        ['2', "Doloros St", 67898, '2 Choco Rd, 69412 Eberbach']], 
    columns=['id', "Street", 'Postcode', 'FullAddress']
)

m = df['Street'].isna()
print(df["FullAddress"].str.extract(r'(.+?),'))                        # prints street
print(df["FullAddress"].str.extract(r'\b(\d{5})\b'))                   # prints postcode
df.loc[m, 'Street'] = df.loc[m, 'FullAddress'].str.extract(r'(.+?),')  # outputs NaN
df.loc[m, 'Postcode'] = df.loc[m, 'FullAddress'].str.extract(r'\b(\d{5})\b')
# trying where method throws error - NotImplementedError: cannot align with a higher dimensional NDFrame
df["Street"] = df["Street"].where(~(df["Street"].isna()), df["FullAddress"].str.extract(r'(.+?),'))
```

What I'm trying to do is fill the empty Street and Postcode with the values from FullAddress - without disturbing the existing Street and Postcode values.

There is no problem with the indexing, the regex, or even the extract... I've read the docs, searched for anything similar... What does every get, but I don't understand!?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `expand=False` as parameter of `str.extract`:

```
>>> df.loc[m, 'FullAddress'].str.extract(r'(.+?),')

             0  # <- it's not a Series but a DataFrame with one column
0  1 Banana St

>>> df.loc[m, 'FullAddress'].str.extract(r'(.+?),', expand=False)

0    1 Banana St
Name: FullAddress, dtype: object  # <- now it's a Series
```

In the first version, Pandas can't align column labels `Street` vs `0`. In the second version, the Series fit into the `Street` Series, so:

```
df.loc[m, 'Street'] = df.loc[m, 'FullAddress'].str.extract(r'(.+?),', expand=False)
df.loc[m, 'Postcode'] = df.loc[m, 'FullAddress'].str.extract(r'\b(\d{5})\b', expand=False)
print(df)

# Output
  id       Street Postcode                    FullAddress
0  1  1 Banana St    69126  1 Banana St, 69126 Heidelberg
1  2   Doloros St  67898.0     2 Choco Rd, 69412 Eberbach
```

**Update***: it's possible to use `extract` without `expand=False` using named groups `(?P<xxx>...)` to align column labels:

```
df.loc[m, 'Street'] = df.loc[m, 'FullAddress'].str.extract(r'(?P<Street>.+?),')
df.loc[m, 'Postcode'] = df.loc[m, 'FullAddress'].str.extract(r'\b(?P<Postcode>\d{5})\b')

# OR

pattern = r'(?P<Street>.+?),\s*\b(?P<Postcode>\d{5})\b'
df.loc[m, ['Street', 'Postcode']] = df.loc[m, 'FullAddress'].str.extract(pattern)
```

Comment: I had a feeling I'd be embarrassed by this question. In my real data there is only ever 1 comma, and only one 5 digit value, so I thought it would align as a dataframe or series. The doc.s actually show why it doesn't. Thanks for the clarification. I'll leave the dumb question with your clever answer in case there is someone else who doesn't know the difference between a series and a dataframe with one column.

Comment: No you should not. It's a good question. Text functions are not so obvious: difference between extract, extractall and find, findall...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to fill in the NaN values in your dataframe:

```
df["Street"] = df["Street"].fillna(df["FullAddress"].str.extract(r'(.+?),')[0])
df["Postcode"] = df["Postcode"].fillna(df["FullAddress"].str.extract(r'\b(\d{5})\b')[0])
```

This will fill in all of your null values with the result of the `extract` while keeping all existing values:

```
  id       Street Postcode                    FullAddress
0  1  1 Banana St    69126  1 Banana St, 69126 Heidelberg
1  2   Doloros St    67898     2 Choco Rd, 69412 Eberbach
```